# when should i use f.read() and when should i use "for i in f" , here f refers to file object

Tags: python, file

when to iterate and when to use function , Dont they give same result?
I tried both and received similar result , when to use what??
also if possible please give a comparative scenario analysis of what to use when with example

Comment: Here is the Python documentation, on reading and writing files.  _[Python 3.12.1 documentation – The Python Tutorial – 7.2. Reading and Writing Files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)_.

Answer (score 2):

`f.read()` reads the entire file into a single string variable. If you want to process this line by line, you'll need to split it and loop over that. If the file is large, reading it all may take some time, and you'll use lots of memory.

`for line in f:` just processes the file one line at a time. It can start processing as soon as it has read the first line, it doesn't have to wait for all of it to be loaded into memory. Operating systems typically perform read-ahead, so when it needs the next block of the file it will already be in memory. And you only need memory for one line, not the entire file.

So the loop will often have better performance because of read-ahead, memory reduction, and pipelining.

But if you're not processing the file line by line, `f.read()` will often be more appropriate.